# TextField gets hidden when the keyboard pops in

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter

```
import 'package:e_expense/home.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignUpPage extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
  _SignUpState createState() => _SignUpState();
 }

class _SignUpState extends State<SignUpPage> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
     appBar: AppBar(
      iconTheme: IconThemeData(
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text(
        "Welcome to E-Expense",
        style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
            color: Colors.green),
      ),
      elevation: 0.0,
      backgroundColor: Color(0x00000000).withOpacity(0),
    ),
    body: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(
          fit: FlexFit.loose,
          child: Container(
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                  child: Text(
                    "Signup",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 80.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(270.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                  child: Text(
                    ".",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.green,
                      fontSize: 80.0,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'USER NAME',
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'EMAIL',
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'PASSWORD',
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 10.0),
              TextField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'REPEAT PASSWORD',
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 40.0),
              ButtonBar(
                alignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {},
                      child: Text(
                        'CANCEL',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      )),
                  RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (BuildContext context) => HomePage(),
                          fullscreenDialog: false));
                    },
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Text(
                      'SIGNUP',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                      fontSize: 15.0),

                    ),
                    textColor: Colors.white,
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ));
 }
}
```

Hello all this is my first flutter app. I have been trying to create a sign up page with few textfields. Everything looks good, but whenever I click on any textfield softkeyboard shows and hide the text filed(please see the attached images)
[image: keyboard hiding the textfield]
[image: textfields without keyboard]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few changes:

- Set `resizeToAvoidBottomPadding` true
- Remove the `Flexible` Widget
- Wrap your first `Column` inside `SingleChildScrollView`

  ```
   @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
          appBar: AppBar(
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Text(
              "Welcome to E-Expense",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                  color: Colors.green),
            ),
            elevation: 0.0,
            backgroundColor: Color(0x00000000).withOpacity(0),
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  child: Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "Signup",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 80.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(270.0, 50.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                        child: Text(
                          ".",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.green,
                            fontSize: 80.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 35.0, left: 20.0, right: 20.0),
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'USER NAME',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.green,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                        TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'EMAIL',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.green,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                        TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'PASSWORD',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.green,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                        TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            labelText: 'REPEAT PASSWORD',
                            labelStyle: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.green,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 40.0),
                        ButtonBar(
                          alignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            FlatButton(
                                onPressed: () {},
                                child: Text(
                                  'CANCEL',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                )),
                            RaisedButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (BuildContext context) => null,
                                    fullscreenDialog: false));
                              },
                              color: Colors.green,
                              child: Text(
                                'SIGNUP',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 15.0),
                              ),
                              textColor: Colors.white,
                            )
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ));
    }
  ```

Comment: This is the only thing that's worked for me Set resizeToAvoidBottomPadding true

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the **widget** that contains those `TextField`s with a `SingleChildScrollView`.

Answer (score 1):

Please use

android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
in forAndroidManifest.xml for activity SignUpPage

Comment: This will only make it work for Android, what about iOS?

Comment: manage edit text in a scroll view, and manage offset to visible item.

Comment: and use KeyboardAvoidingView for react.